# Правильное употребление слова «обаполо»

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, точное-словоупотребление, разговорная-речь

Попался такой синоним к выражению "с обеих сторон". В нацкорпусе есть пара примеров, которые особо не помогают ответить на вопрос, можно ли сказать нечто вроде "он и она обаполо шкафа" — то есть с двух противоположных сторон шкафа (пример просто произвольный).

Если так сказать нельзя, то хотелось бы более-менее развёрнутый ответ насчёт того, в каком же контексте слово "обаполо" будет правильно употребляться со значением "по обе стороны".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **оба́поло** (в значении "с обеих сторон") имеется в словаре русских говоров ([**стр. 348–349**](https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/21.pdf)). В нем много похожих слов (оба́пол, обапо́л, обапа́л, оба́поло, оба́полы, оба́полами) и много значений. Вот одно из них — то, о котором вы спрашиваете.

**I.** **Оба́пол, обапо́л** и **обапа́л**, *наречие* и *предлог с род. пад.*

1. По обе стороны; около, вокруг, возле. = Оба́пол. Ряз., Колуж., Тамб., Влад., Даль. Пенз., Ворон. *Поискали его обапол гумен, не нашли. Обапол все деревни сгорели.* Тул. *Обапол дороги березы. Мужики живут обапол речки.* Смол. Зап. Брян. *Обапол печи, обапол стены.* Новг. Слов. Акад. 1959 [с пометами «устар.» и «обл.»]. Обапол. Слов. Акад. 1847 [с пометой «церк.»]. *Обапол речки леса, деревья, обапол сосняк растет, с обоих сторон болота.* Кыштов. Новосиб. 1972. ° О б а п а́ л. Курск., Ряз., Твер., Макаров, 1844. Тамб. = О б а́ п ы л. Тамб., 1852.

**II. Оба́пола, оба́поло** и **оба́полы**, *наречие* и *предлог с род. пад.*

1. То же, что 1. Оба́пол (в 1-м знач.). = О б а́ п о л а. Тул., 1820. *Так и ходит во оба́пола его.* Тул. *Оба́пола деревни.* Курск. *Он оба́поло моего двора живет.* Орл. Ворон., Ряз., Калуж., Тамб., Влад. = О б а́ п ол о. Казан., 1847. Сарат. *Обаполо купцы похаживают, За бока быка похватывают.* Курск. Тамб. *Я проходил обаполо пруда.* Ворон. Влад., Калуж., Орл., Тул.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по этой подборке словарных статей, https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB
слово сохранилось в нескольких *диалектах*. В тех, которые перечислил Даль (ряз. калужск. тамб. влад.), предложное значение "по обе стороны" не приводится, хотя у него дан добрый десяток примеров употребления. У Фасмера это значение приведено для *смоленского* диалекта, с указанием на истоки из русского языка 14 века. Поэтому трудно предположить, кто и где в наше время сможет правильно понять употребление этого предлога со значением распределения *разных* предметов или субъектов "по обе стороны" чего-либо.